prism.js isn't colorizing PHP
I am trying to use prism.js to highlight some PHP code examples, but it's not working.  Code:
<pre class="language-php">
<code class="language-php">
$var = abs(-4.2);
var_dump($var);
// float(4.2)
</code>
</pre>

How it looks in browser:

The prism css and js files are linked to the page.  How do I get this PHP code colorized?

you got 7000 points and don't know how to write a proper question :) how do u import it? how do you load it? did u load markup-templating? show the code you are running to color it not the code you want to color!

@FlashThunder ? This is a basic implementation.  A small PHP page with an example of a PHP function with includes to bring in the header and footer.  Just a link tag to bring in prism.css at the top and prism.js at the bottom of the page.  No JS MVC framework.  I have some web pages made this way with JavaScript code examples (change 'php' to 'javascript' in pre and code tags), and that example JavaScript code is rendering colorized.  I didn't think I needed to cut-and-paste all 80 lines of the HTML page

if we can't reproduce it then how can we help you? you simply asked "why the result of my unknown scripts look like that?"

@FlashThunder I see your point that given the 'code' I've included, there's not much to work with to fix.  Weird js library to work with.  I thought the answer would be something relatively simple bc this works for my js code examples

You probably didn't import markup-templating module, as it is said in documentation for PHP highlighting.

@FlashThunder Your comment led me to the answer.  Thanks

Prism.js can highlight the syntax of about 100 languages.  To keep the JavaScript and CSS files as small as possible, you specify which language(s) you want/opt in on it's web site (https://prismjs.com/download.html) and build your custom files.  I did not add PHP (it has JavaScript by default) initially, and when I re-made my prism files with PHP, it worked.
